# Razor Pages Ajax 400 Status

Tags: .net-core, razor-pages

I'm getting a

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()

error when I try to make an Ajax request to call a handler on my page.

**/main.js**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Products/Edit?handler=GetAliases",
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
            $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
    },
    data: { "id": 1 },
    success: function (response) {
        $('#product-aliases-container').html(response);
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        alert('failure: ' + response.responseText);
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert('error: ' + response.responseText);
    }
});
```

**/Products/Edit.cshtml.cs**

```
public class EditModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly MyProject.Models.MyDatabaseContext _context;

    public EditModel(MyProject.Models.MyDatabaseContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    ...


    public IEnumerable<ProductAlias> Aliases { get; set; } = default!;
    public PartialViewResult OnGetGetAliases(int? id)
    {
        var aliases = _context.ProductAliases.Where(m => m.ProductId == id);

        Aliases = aliases;

        return Partial("_AssetAliasList", Aliases);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/701086/ajax-post-request-with-razor-pages-and-full-calend).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common causes for failed AJAX posts resulting in a 400 status code are:

1. The CSRF token was generated but the  was not included in the posted
   payload
2. The CSRF token was included in the post, but in a way that prevented
   its discovery on the server.
3. No CSRF token was generated because the form tag helper was not used.

You are getting a 400 (Bad Request) response because the framework expects the RequestVerificationToken as part of the posted request.  If your request does not have this information, the framework will return the 400 bad request. Your current code is not sending it

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/",
    data: { foo: "bar" },
    headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
    success: function (response) {
```

Comment: If you are going to copy content directly from my site, it would be nice to get some attribution https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/336/ajax-posts-in-razor-pages-and-http-400-errors

Comment: Great to know my knowledge can be found on your website, :) why the way ! didn't copy.

Comment: It's virtually word for word.